# Mysterious "Type Error: non-native scope object" in Firebug

Tags: javascript, macos, firefox, firebug, swfobject

Consider the following HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
Test page

<!--Start of Zopim Live Chat Script-->
<script type="text/javascript">
window.$zopim||(function(d,s){var z=$zopim=function(c){z._.push(c)},$=z.s=
d.createElement(s),e=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];z.set=function(o){z.set.
_.push(o)};z._=[];z.set._=[];$.async=!0;$.setAttribute('charset','utf-8');
$.src='//cdn.zopim.com/?pTR0FiicfJ4aMcmuHI9HfVAB4uzKeFIT';z.t=+new Date;$.
type='text/javascript';e.parentNode.insertBefore($,e)})(document,'script');
</script>
<!--End of Zopim Live Chat Script-->

<script type="text/javascript" async="">
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var b = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
    var o = document.createElement("object");
    o.setAttribute("type", "application/x-shockwave-flash");
    var t = b.appendChild(o);
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/V9jtD/

It contains Zopim widget code, another async script that just adds an "object" tag to DOM. Let the above file be served by a webserver (you can use the jsFiddle: http://fiddle.jshell.net/V9jtD/show/). Open it in MacOSX Firefox 15+ with Firebug activated.

You will see the following error repeated many times:

```
TypeError: non-native scope object
```

If the errors donot show up, just refresh the page. And mainly Zopim fails to show up (sometimes appears with incomplete functionality). I could not reproduce this in Firefox/Ubuntu. (It might be reproducible in Firefox/Windows I could not check).

However, in the following cases Zopim loads fine:

1. Comment out "var t = b.appendChild(o);" (ie. dont append the "object" tag to DOM, or you can just remove second script tag entirely).
2. Deactivate Firebug.

**I essentially want to understand who is causing the error so I can debug it.**

**Is it Firebug, because deactivating it Zopim works fine? But then removing the second script tag with Firebug enabled does not cause the error.**

**Is it the second script tag, because removing it Zopim works fine? But then deactivate Firebug and Zopim works fine even with second script tag.**

**Or is it Zopim itself?**

Note that the content in the second script tag is part of function testPlayerVersion() in swfobject.js. I have hit this error when I am trying to add Zopim to a page that already has swfobject.

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be easier to work out if the fiddle wasn't loading minified JS from Zopim, but the offending line (roughly beautified) is:

```
try {
    (0)()
} catch (v) {
    s = v.arguments ?
        'chrome' : v.stack ?
        'firefox' : window.opera && !('stacktrace' in v) ?
        'opera' : 'other'
}
```

Which looks like a hacky way of detecting the browser. I'm not sure why it's causing Firebug to bail, it might be worth raising an issue with them if it's reproducible.

Comment: Just add "try { undefined_function(); } catch(e) {}" below "var t = b.appendChild(o);" in the second script. You will now see error "non-native scope object" against "undefined_function();" when you should see no error at all as you are just ignoring it with catch. Something is wrong with swfobject+Zopim+Firebug. Remove anyone and things work fine.

Comment: Also, there is no error in the above line if I completely remove the second script tag (the one which inserts "object" into DOM).

Comment: Sounds like a firebug bug then. Doesn't seem to be reproducible in the Webkit inspector.

Comment: Actually, that doesn't look like it. Minimal example works fine in Firebug: http://jsfiddle.net/cQcRA/1/.

Comment: The error occurs only when all three are present: Zopim, swfobject  (or the minimal second script tag as in the question) and Firebug enabled. You can remove/disable swfobject or Firebug and there is no error.