# TypeError: non-native scope object

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jwplayer

I sometimes get this error in my jwplayer: `TypeError: non-native scope object`

This means that one video out of multiple videos I have has failed to load. This makes it unreliable. My question is that is there a way to make it more reliable and permanently fix this error?

Below is code:

```
<?php

$key = $_GET['key'];
$i = $_GET['i'];
$v = $_GET['v'];

?>
<div id="myElement-<?php echo $key.'-'.$i; ?>">Loading the player...

<script type="text/javascript">
jwplayer("myElement-<?php echo $key.'-'.$i; ?>").setup({
    file: "<?php echo 'VideoFiles/'.$v; ?>",
    width: 480,
    height: 270
});

</script>

</div>
```

Comment: Make sure there are no spaces or '(' etc. in your filename.

Comment: Also do you have a link to where you are having the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it possibly a firebug issue if you are using firefox with firebug enabled?, look [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14007062/mysterious-type-error-non-native-scope-object-in-firebug)